# Error when deploying AWS CDK nested stack: ValidationError for stackName

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript, nested-stack

I'm encountering an error when trying to deploy a nested AWS CDK stack as part of my main stack, and I'm having trouble understanding and resolving it.

The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Error [ValidationError]: 2 validation errors detected: Value '' at 'stackName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]|arn:[-a-zA-Z0-9:/._+]; Value '' at 'stackName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1

Error occurred while monitoring stack: Error [ValidationError]: 2 validation errors detected: Value '' at 'stackName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*|arn:[-a-zA-Z0-9:/._+]*; Value '' at 'stackName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1
        at Request.extractError (/home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:46430)
        at Request.callListeners (/home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:90083)
        at Request.emit (/home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:89531)
        at Request.emit (/home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:196289)
        at Request.transition (/home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:189841)
        at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:154713)
        at /home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:155043
        at Request.<anonymous> (/home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:190133)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:196364)
        at Request.callListeners (/home/pankaj/work/optimizory/rmsis-cdk-prod/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:362:90251) {
      code: 'ValidationError',
      time: 2023-10-11T07:11:47.628Z,
      requestId: '624d1704-0a35-4d37-8cfc-3a21d1ead226',
      statusCode: 400,
      retryable: false,
      retryDelay: 288.2824464668148
    }
```

I'm using nested stacks in AWS CDK, and it appears that this error is related to the `stackName` of one of the nested stacks. I've checked my code, and it appears to follow the naming constraints for AWS CloudFormation stack names.

Here's a simplified version of my CDK code, with a focus on the nested stack:

```js
const stack = new ClientStack(this, "cli-"+clients[i].tenantId , stackprops);
```

I'm using AWS CDK version 2.84.0

Comment: Please add the code where you're creating the actual `NestedStack` and where you're setting/passing the `stackName` prop

Comment: I don't think the same code is enough.`Value '' at 'stackName'` you have an empty `stackName` prop somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue on the previous aws-cdk version.
I upgraded the aws-cdk globally and it resolved the issue. [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html). [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/27746)

```
npm install -g aws-cdk
```